# Pattern in factorising monic Quadratics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have noticed a pattern while factoring quadratic expressions in the form: $x^2+(a+1)x+a$ ($a$ is a constant). For example,

1. $x^2+3x+2=(x+2)(x+1)$
2. $x^2+92x+91=(x+91)(x+1)$
3. $x^2+5x+4=(x+4)(x+1)$

The pattern which can be assumed here is:

$$x^2+(a+1)x+a=(x+a)(x+1)$$

My question is: How do you prove this identity?

Comment: Expand both sides.

Comment: Just put a pair of dollar signs at the beginning and end of your equations. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways other than direct factorization:

- by the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) the roots of $\,x^2+(a+1)x+a\,$ are $$\,x_{1,2}=\dfrac{-(a+1)\pm\sqrt{(a+1)^2-4a}}{2}=\dfrac{-(a+1)\pm\sqrt{(a-1)^2}}{2}=\begin{cases}-1 \\-a\end{cases}\,$$and therefore the quadratic factors as $\,(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=(x+1)(x+a)\,$;
- two quadratics that have equal values at three different points are identical (since their difference would be a polynomial of degree $\le 2$ with $3$ roots), so it is enough to verify that $\,x^2+(a+1)x+a=(x+1)(x+a)\,$ for three values of $x$, for example $x=0,-1,-a$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the given identity, you will use the distributive property of real numbers. Let's expand the RHS (right hand side):

$(x+a)(x+1)=(x+a)x+(x+a)(1)=x^2+ax+x+a=x^2+x(a+1)+a$ which proves the result. In the last step, I simply factorized the middle expression $ax+x$ by removing the common factor $x$. This is justified, again, by the Distributive Property of real numbers.

Hope this helps you! :)